# Android SupportFragment add and replace animations

Tags: android, animation, replace, fragment, addition

For a project, I need to retain the state of fragments during navigation.
I've implemented a system that works pretty well, every time a fragment is destroyed or restored I've callbacks with the saved data.

I use the same callbacks to perform some accessory operations (like change the state of the header bar)

Problem is that this behavior works **only** with the *replace* transaction, but the customer asked for animations *ios style* (slide left and right), for which I'll have to use the *add* transaction.

But *add* doesn't trigger any callbacks to save or restore the data, so also the behavior of the header bar is completely messed up among other things.

It's possibile to emulate the animation's behavior of the *add* transaction with the *replace* one?

Thank you

Comment: post the code please

Comment: Sorry am not able to get your question. You want to animate add or replace?